# Detecting multiple lines in OpenCV HoughLines

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCV 4.4 and running the following code to detect lines of a grid. When I display the image it always detect one line as shown in the screenshot. How can I detect all vertical lines in the grid?

```
grid = cv2.imread('images/grid.jpeg')

grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(grid, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(grayscale, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 100)

for rho, theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))
    cv2.line(grid, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Lines", grid)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Original Image:
[image]

Comment: can you imshow edges image?

Comment: @Micka added the original image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lineDetector` algorithm.

- Find the edges of your image, as @Micka suggested

---

- ```py
  img = cv2.imread("lines.png")
  img_gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  img_cny = cv2.Canny(img_gry, 50, 200)
  ```
- Result:

  ---

  - [image]
- To detect the vertical edges, the difference between x-coordinates should be close to 0 Since only y-coordinates are changing.

  - ```py
    if abs(x1 - x2) < 3:
        cv2.line(img, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2), color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=3)
    ```
- Result:

---

- [image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("lines.png")
img_gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_cny = cv2.Canny(img_gry, 50, 200)

lns = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(img_cny)

for ln in lns:
    x1 = int(ln[0][0])
    y1 = int(ln[0][1])
    x2 = int(ln[0][2])
    y2 = int(ln[0][3])

    if abs(x1 - x2) < 3:
        cv2.line(img, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2), color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=3)

cv2.imshow("lns", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```